# Tracking changes to my Git configuration?

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a canonical way to track changes to my git configuration?

Context: A coworker and I are comparing our various git settings, both global and per-repo, and we would like to see the various changes we have both made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could store your Git (and other) configuration files in a dedicated Git repo and then symlink them to their usage locations.

This may be of interest: http://blog.smalleycreative.com/tutorials/using-git-and-github-to-manage-your-dotfiles/

Comment: I'm using [Homesick](https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick) for that purpose: https://github.com/nwinkler/dotfiles/blob/master/home/.gitconfig